# Group homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

In the book Algebra of Serge Lang, the following is written:
"The fact that Hom(G,X) is a group when G,X are commutative is of special significance."
(Where Hom(G,X) is the set of homomorphisms from G into X) My question is:
What is the binary operation of the group Hom(G,X)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing it's composition.

Comment: It is the group operation in $X$: $f+g(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.

Comment: It can't be composition. Hom(G,X) may not be closed under this operation.

Comment: Not only "may not be closed": it can't be closed unless $\,X=G\,$

Comment: Thanks Steve, this makes sense.

Comment: I guess now that we only need X to be commutative. We don't need G to be Abelian, do we?

Comment: No, we don't need, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve commented, $f+g:= \big( x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)\big)$, this is the operation (so called '*pointwise* operation').

In general, for algebraic structures $(X,*)$ with one binary operation, then, the homsets $hom(X,Y)$ are naturally closed wrt. ($*$ defined pointwise) if and only if
$$(a*b)*(c*d)=(a*c)*(b*d)$$
holds for all elements $a,b,c,d\in Y$. And, it fits perfectly for Abelian groups.